# dynamic switch-case - Text based RPG

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm fairly new to advanced programming and I'd like to practice all my knowledge with some exercises. For that I developed a little text-based RPG which can be guided through a switch-case method in my test class.

Is there a better way to develop such a game with java? Right now I can only use predefined commands and it feels  little static.

Would appreciate every advice!
Thank you

```
public class Game {

    static void ManageGame() {

        String input = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!input.equals("close game")) {

            input = sc.next();

            switch (input) {
              case "Start Game":
                  StartGame();
            }

        }

       sc.close();

     }

     static void StartGame() {
         System.out.println(Player.getInstance().toString() + " has spawned");
     }
}
```

And in the Testclass I just call the method Game.ManageGame();

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: Ofc I'm at the beginning of my little project, but I just want to know if the approach is good or bad and how I could improve it

Comment: ok, let me take a look

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure, but in general your code is actually very clean and good. But don't forget the break in your switch case as in the following example:

```
    String fruit = "Apple";

    switch (fruit) {
        case "Apple":
            System.out.println("It is a Apple");
            break;
        case "Banana":
            System.out.println("It is a Banana");
            break;
        case "Grapefruit":
            System.out.println("It is a Grapefruit");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch case is static, compiler prepares jump tables at compile time.